# trouble clicking on dropdown sub-menu through selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium

I am automating a website using selenium webdriver. The problem i am facing is that when i click on a menu item, the submenu opens, (its actually a misplaced dropdown, ui problem) , i can find the element of the sub menu item i want to click on, but i am not able to click as i get an exception :

"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element"

Is there any way i can click on this submenu item?

HTML code for the page:

```
<td class="menulevel1norm" id="PanelTable" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenu20111219065812407304,this,'.menuitempopuprownormal','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');">
Text -  Inbound  
<div id="divMenu20111219065812407304" style="border-top-width: medium; border-right-width: medium; border-bottom-width: medium; border-left-width: medium; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" name="actiondiv">
<div myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/omreceipt.search';">
![enter image description here][4]Text - MENU_Receipt Console
```

My Java Code for Webdriver :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      rt.exec("taskkill /F /IM IEDriverServer.exe /T");
      WebDriver driver = UtilityMethods.driverinitialize();
      driver.get("xxxx");
      UtilityMethods.login(driver); 
      WebElement e1 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("wicket-generated-id-4")));
        e1.click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame("frame4");
        String eletext;
         List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("PanelTable"));
         for(WebElement ele : elements){
             eletext = ele.getText();
             System.out.println(eletext);
             if(eletext.equals(" Inbound ")){
                 ele.click();
                 break;
             }
         }

         Thread.sleep(2000);
         List<WebElement> elements2 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
         for(WebElement ele1 : elements2){
             eletext = ele1.getAttribute("myonclick");
             System.out.println(eletext);
             if(eletext == null){ 
                 continue; }
    else if(eletext.equals("window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/omreceipt.search';")){
                     ele1.click();
                    break;
             }
         }



}
```

Comment: Could you clarify which of the element(s) you do want to click on? From your code above I'm guessing `ele1` but a little guidance will likely help us help you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark, i am tyring to click on submenu with text  "MENU_Receipt Console", and yes i have searched for its attribute myonclick, and i am clicking it through WebElement variable ele1.

Comment: So you click on the element with the ID `PanelTable`, )are there more than one on the page? I'm guessing there is due to your for loop but thought it best to check) and that reveals the 2 `div` elements and you want to click on the second but you're getting the exception that it isn't visible? Sorry again trying to full understand the problem.

Comment: yes, there are multiple elements with the same id and tags, so i am  identifying them with their unique attributes, the element is found, but it does not click on it, and gives the exception :(

Comment: It seems strange that it can find the correct element but can't click on it. Can you show a screen shot of what it looks like?

Comment: hi Mark, can you please share your email, because i cannot attach images here as my reputation is low, i will mail you the screens

Answer (score 0):

First, wait for all elements to appear on-page. Then if the element is properly visible and not overlapping with other parts of another element then click will perform. Another way is to locate a nearby proper element and then moving the pointer to some offset and then performing click.